# Rails- Testing Devise. reset password.Opening link in mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, mailer

I'm trying to test the devise feature for reseting a password, but I'm having some issues trying to test the link in the mail and visiting the page that is linked to.

I've tried unsuccessfully 2 ways to do it:

1)

```
scenario "User resets his password" do
  user2 = FactoryGirl.create(
  :user, reset_password_token: "new_password",
)

  visit new_user_password_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user2.email
  click_on "Send me reset password instructions"

  open_email(user2.email)
  click_first_link_in_email
  expect(page).to have_content("Reset your password")

end
```

If I do this I get the error:

```
Failure/Error: click_first_link_in_email

 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/1999/xhtml'"
```

2)

```
scenario "User resets his password" do
  user2 = FactoryGirl.create( :user, reset_password_token: "new_password" )
  visit edit_user_password_path(reset_password_token:   
  expect(page).to have_content("Reset your password")
  end
```

If I do this it takes me to the initial page saying:

```
  "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email"
```

Comment: after reset_password_token: I have a 
     user2.reset_password_token)

Comment: The second example is understandable. It needs to go through a mail and click the reset password link from the mail. I will suggest you use [letter opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) or [mail catcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher)

Comment: Why are you testing this @Westey? Devise is already tested and mantained. I guess you should not worry about such testings.

Comment: I'm using mailcatcher, and everything works great but I can't get to that page in the test environment (page to introduce the new passwords).
I need to add extra security and extra tests, for particular reasons of the website's nature :S

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
there were more links inside the mail.
The way that I selected the one that I wanted was by using links_in_email(email).
I used pry to check the links inside the array (links_in_email(email) and then select the one that I was interested in.

```
scenario "User resets his password" do
  visit new_user_password_path
  fill_in "Email", with: @user.email
  click_on "Send me reset password instructions"

  mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  link = links_in_email(mail)[1]

  visit link
  expect(page).to have_content("Reset your password")
end
```